# count distinct within haml template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, haml

I am wondering if there is a way to count distinct with my haml template, I have tried using group_by(&:product_id) with no success. the below code gives me a count but not unique

```
- @suppliers.each do |supplier|
        %tr
          %td.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric= link_to supplier.name, edit_admin_supplier_path(supplier)
          %td.mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric= supplier.variants.product.count
```

Comment: Don't query in the view if possible. Also this will give you a nasty n+1 query.

Comment: are you saying i should perform this query within the model?

Comment: Or in the controller - you will most likely want to use a join with a subquery to fetch the count. Exactly how to do that depends on what DB and the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify DISTINCT COUNT in a query `select` call.  You can use it like this:

```
supplier.variants.product.select("DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS COUNT")
```

Not really knowing how your schema and models are designed, so the `select` might need to be chained earlier into the query.  However, you can certainly insert this into your HAML.

As Max already pointed out, avoid doing queries in your view, if possible.  If it's not possible, rethink your design, because it may be forcing you down a bad road.